# Im creating a VM using terraform code in GCP. I would like to inject a script that runs when the vm is created upon startup

Tags: powershell, google-cloud-platform, terraform, google-compute-engine

Here is what I have, its not working:

```
metadata_startup_script = <<-SCRIPT
<powershell>
# Set execution policy to RemoteSigned
Set-ExecutionPolicy -ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned -Scope LocalMachine -Force

# PowerShell script to rename the computer
$newName = "mktestcomputer$($count.index + 1)" # Set your desired computer name here
$computerInfo = Get-WmiObject Win32_ComputerSystem
$computerInfo.Rename($newName)
Restart-Computer -Force
</powershell>
SCRIPT
```

It's being executed on Win2022 OS, but it does not run. The VMs both get created with disks, but do not get renamed. Any ideas how to get that working?

Comment: What is the new name? What is the return value from `Rename`? If there is an error, what is the error?

Comment: If I run the code on the created/deployed VMs, the rename works and its called mktestcomputer. But I get no error when applying the TF code. Im gonna try alternate syntax tomorrow

Comment: Can you troubleshoot the startup script using one of these methods mentioned in the [doc](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/startup-scripts/windows#viewing-output)

Comment: `"mktestcomputer$($count.index + 1)"` I get a feeling that interpolation syntax is not correct ... what do you get in the terraform plan?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks all. Turns out there were a few problems there. Here is what Im using now that works great. It renames and joins the domain, and sets the TZ and logs as well. I run this on my target to create the PW file:

```
alternate method of securing passwords

# Pre-generate a key and save it for later use.
$Key = New-Object Byte[] 32
[Security.Cryptography.RNGCryptoServiceProvider]::Create().GetBytes($Key)
$Key | out-file c:\Windows\Startup\aes.key
# Copy the key file into remote computer

# Get a credential and use pre-generated key for encryption
# Save the encrypted password on a file
(get-credential).Password | ConvertFrom-SecureString -key (get-content 
c:\Windows\Startup\aes.key) | set-content "c:\Windows\Startup\password.txt"
```

and here is the metadata:

```
metadata = {
  windows-startup-script-ps1 = <<-script
  # PowerShell script to rename the computer and join AD
  Start-Transcript -path c:\Windows\Startup\output.txt -append
  # Check if the marker file exists
  if (Test-Path -Path "C:\Windows\Startup\Markerfile.txt") {
    exit
  } else {
  $password = Get-Content C:\Windows\Startup\password.txt | ConvertTo-SecureString -Key (Get-Content C:\Windows\Startup\aes.key)
  $userName = "some username here"
  $credential = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PsCredential($username,$password)
  $domain = "mydomain.com"
  Add-Computer -DomainName $domain -Credential $Credential -NewName "MYIMAGE" -Force -Restart
  Set-TimeZone -Name 'US Eastern Standard Time' -PassThru
  # Create a marker file to indicate that the script has run once
  New-Item -ItemType File -Path "C:\Windows\Startup\Markerfile.txt"
  }
  Stop-Transcript
  script
```

}